# ¿Por qué no salta a la siguiente línea del .txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    exec(open("selectorproxy.py").read())
    proxy = open("proxys.txt", 'r').readline().rstrip("\n")
    #puerto = open("puertos.txt", 'r').readline().rstrip("\n")
    try:
        print(proxy)
        consulta = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+proxy+'/www.fotocasa.es/es/')

    except:
        proxy = open("proxys.txt", 'r').readline(1).rstrip("\n")
        print(proxy)
        consulta = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+proxy+'/www.fotocasa.es/es/')
```

Estoy intentando que una vez lea el primer proxy si este da error, salte al siguiente pero, no lo lee, al añadir `proxy = open("proxys.txt", 'r').readline(1).rstrip("\n")` solo imprime el primer caracter de la primera línea y no salta a leer la siguiente. El error es

> urllib.error.URLError: o host given><urlopen error n

Comment: El parámetro de `readline` no indica la línea a leer sino la cantidad de bytes que quieres leer. `getline` devuelve la siguiente linea. Pero cómo estás creando un nuevo stream cada vez, se lee desde el principio. Mejor guardalo en una variable.  https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readline.asp

Comment: ¿a qué te refieres con guardarlo en una variable? puedes explicarme cómo hacerlo? por favor

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar el propósito de `exec(open("selectorproxy.py").read())` ?

Comment: Ejecuta un Script que hice antes para guardar una lista de proxys de diferentes webs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El flujo de trabajo con archivos o streams debería ser el siguiente:

```
# Abres el archivo / creas el stream
stream = open(file="archivo.txt", mode="rwt")

# Puedes leer línea a línea
linea1 = stream.readline()
linea2 = stream.readline()
linea3 = stream.readline()
...

# Puedes obtener un arreglo con todas las líneas
líneas = stream.readlines()

# Cierras el archivo / stream al terminar de leer o escribir en el
stream.close()
```

Algo que debes tener en cuenta es que un stream es como una máquina de estado.

Un stream es como una tabla con un "marcador" en una posición determinada. Normalmente ese marcador inicia en 0. Es a partir de ese marcador que se producen las lecturas y escrituras.

Cada vez que lees o escribes al stream, el marcador se mueve. Es por eso que si haces 2 o más llamadas a la función `readline()` sin cambiar la posición del marcador obtendrás información diferente. Y cada vez que llamas a la función `open` obtienes un nuevo stream con el marcador al inicio.

La posición a la que se cambia dicho marcador depende de cuánta información leas/escribas en él.

Como el stream tiene este marcador, hay un función que cambia su posición, [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.seek), y [`tell`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.tell) que devuelve su posición.

Está función toma como primer parámetro `offset` cuánto te quieres mover hacia adelante (un número positivo) o hacia atrás (negativo) y cómo segundo parámetro `whence` a partir de qué punto del stream:

- `SEEK_SET` del inicio. Como no hay información antes del inicio no tiene sentido indicar un `offset` negativo.
- `SEEK_CUR` de la posición actual.
- `SEEK_END` del final. Como luego del final no hay nada más, no tiene sentido usar un `offset` positivo.

Para que entiendas mejor el concepto, supongamos que además tienes el siguiente texto en el stream y que con la función `read` puedes leer un número de caracteres:

```
stream = "abcdefg\nhi"

# Leer 2 caracteres
print(stream.read(3))
# Salida: ab

# Leer 3 caracteres
print(stream.read(3))
# Salida: cde

print(stream.tell())
# Salida: 5

# Volver al inicio
stream.seek(0, SEEK_SET)
# Leer línea
print(stream.readline())
# Salida: abcdefg
# Lee hasta g, puesto que el siguiente carácter es un salto de línea.
```

Información:

- [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)
- [readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readline)
- [readlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readlines)

Comment: Buena respuesta :D Para añadir, en archivos abiertos en el modo "r", el offset en SEEK_CUR y SEEK_END solo puede ser 0. En cambio si el archivo se abre en modo "rb" si puede no ser 0.

Comment: tremendo genio!

Comment: @DanteS. no tengo idea en qué parte de la documentación está eso. Si me pudieras decir, lo agrego a la respuesta. Solo encontré que en los archivos de texto solo puede usar `seek` desde el inicio del archivo en https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: En realidad, lo supe por experiencia. Pero me dediqué a buscar documentación y no hay nada claro. Pero parece que según un comentario en [una pregunta del sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887909/is-there-documentation-for-file-object), esto documenta los métodos del tipo de objeto devuelto por el modo "r": https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek